# How to sum every element in a numpy array divisible by 5 using vectorization?

Tags: python, numpy, sum, modulus

I am looking for a vectorization method for summing all elements of a numpy array that is evenly divisible by 5.

For example, if I have

```
test = np.array([1,5,12,15,20,22])
```

I want to return 40.  I know about the np.sum method, but is there a way to do this using vectorization given the X%5 == 0 conditional?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can use the [`mask`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays) of the matches for `boolean-indexing` to select those elements and then simply sum those, like so -

```
test[test%5==0].sum()
```

Sample step-by-step run -

```
# Input array
In [48]: test
Out[48]: array([ 1,  5, 12, 15, 20, 22])

# Mask of matches
In [49]: test%5==0
Out[49]: array([False,  True, False,  True,  True, False], dtype=bool)

# Select matching elements off input
In [50]: test[test%5==0]
Out[50]: array([ 5, 15, 20])

# Finally sum those elements
In [51]: test[test%5==0].sum()
Out[51]: 40
```